# Find the length of the arc of the hyperbolic spiral $r\theta = a$ lying between $r = a$ and $r = 2a$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried the formula $\ell = \int_a^{2a} \sqrt{r^2 + (r')^2} d\theta$

After integrating I'm stuck at
a $[\log(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x) - \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}x]$ from $r =a$ and $r=2a$. Please help me determine the length.

Please consider x as theta.

Comment: Do you even know how to antidifferentiate $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ ?

Comment: @SakethMalyala Sure I do. Since you asked I edited the question and wrote exactly where I'm stuck. And I would appreciate if you could simply solve the question instead of mocking my integration skills. If I could solve the question I wouldn't have come here in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Then $x=1$, $x=\frac12$ or $\theta=1, \frac12$ not $r=a ,2a$.

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts.

$$\ell=\bigg|[\log(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x) - \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}x]\Big|_1^\frac12\bigg|$$
 $$=\log\dfrac{2(\sqrt2+1)}{\sqrt5+1}+\sqrt5-\sqrt2=1.220・・・.$$